# Sublime SFTP plugin insists on connecting to "example.com"

Tags: sublimetext2

Trying Sublime and SFTP plugin on Windows, I know I've just been dumb but...

If I use the File menu SFTP/FTP browse server command everything works fine.  The connection to my server works and I get a list of files which I can download, edit, upload with no problem.

However, when I try to upload a file (or do anything SFTP related) by right clicking the file name in FOLDERS and selecting 
SFTP Upload file the plugin insists on trying to connect to example.com rather than to the server I created.

In `users/me/Appdata/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/sftp_servers` I have a server config file like below: (some names changed to protect the innocent)

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "sftp",

    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "sync_same_age": true,

    "host": "myhost.name.net",
    "user": "fred",
    //"password": "password",
    //"port": "22",

    "remote_path": "/home/fred/",
    "file_permissions": "664",
    "dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    //"keepalive": 120,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    "ssh_key_file": "/users/fred/cryptoKeys/sshKey.ppk",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    //"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```